# How to move image to particular time in iMovie?

Tags: imovie

So I have been trying to add image to my iMovie. The problem is I want to add the image at for example 2:00 min. But whenever I drag the image to the project, it always goes in the beginning of the movie. Is there a way I can just drag and drop it to whatever time I want to add it to. This seems to be pretty intuitive but not able to do this.

Comment: Which [iMovie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMovie) version are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about iMovie on the Mac,you can simply drag an image anywhere in the timeline. On iOS, simply position the timeline scrubber at a gap in a space in the timeline where you want your image, and then tap the image from the image chooser.

Comment: If I'm missing something, please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Click on 1 of your highlighted images and drag it into the clip editing/viewing timeline screen to the left diagonal of the photo display screen. You can drag these images anywhere in the timeline. Hope it helps.